# algorithms in python (count letter)

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, count, counter

Python 3. Count letter "linearly"

Input: `aaaabbbbvaa`
Output: `a4b4v1a2`

I did something similar:

```
a = "aaaabbbbvaa"
alist = list(a)
print (alist.count("a"))
```

Comment: What did you try to solve this?

Comment: That just prints `6`

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. This link may help you out: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-frequency-of-each-character-in-string/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem statement stated above is :

```
word = input()
alist=list(word)
alist.append('$')
x=alist[0]
count=0
blist=[alist[0]]
for i in alist:
    if(x==i):
        if(i=='$'):
            blist.append(count)
        count+=1        
    else:
        blist.append(count)
        blist.append(i) 
        count=1
        x=i
blist.remove('$')
for i in blist:
    print(i,end='')
```

Whose Input and Output are:

```
aaaabbbvaa
a4b3v1a2
```

**P.S : This might not be the most optimal way to solve this problem.**